# Camera rotation system isn't orientating itself properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject player;
public Rigidbody rb;
private Vector3 offset;
public Vector3 minCamAngle;
public Vector3 maxCamAngle;

    void Start()
{
    rb = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate()
{
    Quaternion desiredRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.x, minCamAngle.x, maxCamAngle.x), Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.y, minCamAngle.y, maxCamAngle.y), Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.z, minCamAngle.z, maxCamAngle.z)));
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, desiredRotation, Time.deltaTime);
    transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
}
```

This is the code i'm using to rotate the camera based on the players velocity except when i set the minimum and maximum x rotation angle to 34 the camera always sets its rotation to an X rotation of -65.61 at the start of the game. I'm not sure what is happening and some help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: It's not good to set the rotation value manually. Unity recommends using [Transform.Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) instead. 

Can you try if that works better for you?

Maybe, you should also increment rotation instead of just setting the value.

Comment: I tried using transform.Rotate but if i set my min and max camera angles to any positive value the camera just spins on that axis.